# Is it possible to post Facebook questions on behalf of a user?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to post a [Facebook question](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question/) on behalf of a user?

I know that is possible to get the questions that the user has asked and answered, but we could't find some way to automatically ask a question on behalf of a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now post: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/635/